# Number of non- isomorphic digraphs on 3 verticles- with Burnside lemma?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory

How many non isomorphic directed graphs exist with n=3 vertices? (multiple edges allowed, but only one in each directions, no loops)

I can do this only by drawing them: I've got 16.

How can I apply Burnside's lemma?

Answer (score 1):

The isomorphism classes of the directed graphs are the orbits when $S_3$ is acting on the labeled directed graphs. There are $2^6 = 64$ labeled directed graphs total: for each ordered pair of vertices $(v,w)$, there may or may not be an edge $v \to w$.

For each element of $S_3$, we count the number of such graphs fixed by $S_3$. There are only $3$ cases:

- All $64$ graphs are fixed by the identity permutation.
- $(1\;2)$, $(1\;3)$, and $(2\;3)$ fix $8$ graphs. For example, if $(1\;2)$ fixes a graph, then the edge $1 \to 2$ exists iff the edge $2 \to 1$ exists; the edge $1\to 3$ exists iff the edge $2 \to 3$ exists; the edges $3 \to 1$ exists iff the edge $3 \to 2$ exists. So there are only $2^3=8$ choices to make.
- $(1\;2\;3)$ and $(1\;3\;2)$ fix $4$ graphs. For example, if $(1\;2\;3)$ fixes a graph, then all three edges $1 \to 2$, $2 \to 3$, and $3 \to 1$ either exist or don't; separately all three edges $2 \to 1$, $3 \to 2$, and $1 \to 3$ either exist or don't. So there are only $2^2=4$ choices to make.

Averaging, we get $\frac{64 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 4 + 4}{6} = \frac{96}{6}=16$.